# decoding concox gps tracker tcp packet with java

Tags: java, tcp, hex, decode

I'm decoding a [gps tracker](https://www.iconcox.com/products/at1-asset-gps-tracker.html) tcp packet following this reading map:

[image: reading map]

As it said, total length of content should be 0x11 that equals to 17 bytes.
This packet starts with two bytes 0x7878 (120 120) and ends with 0x0D0A (13 10).
But in action, i got the following byte array.

[image: received byte array]

The length of Information content is more than 17 bytes. But if i want to map [-17 -65 -67] sequence as one byte, it becomes 17 bytes.
I don't know how map this three negative byes to one byte. By the way it's just a guess.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

> org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(bytes)

solved the problem.